# Convert List of POCOs to List of JSON Serialized Strings

Tags: c#, json.net

**Context:**
I have a job that uploads data to BigQuery and I am looking to speed it up a bit.  In order to upload the API requires an IEnumerable of serialized data rows rather than a standard json array.

**Problem:**
I currently am doing the following:

```
    public async Task InsertCatalogItemsAsync(IEnumerable<CatalogItem> items)
    {

       //---THIS IS THE PART SLOWING ME DOWN---
       IEnumerable<string> jsonItems = items.Select(i =>
      {
          var serializedItem = JsonSerializer.Serialize(i);
          return serializedItem;
      }).ToList();
       //^^^^^^THIS IS THE PART SLOWING ME DOWN^^^^^

      //upload to BigQuery
      await _table.UploadJsonAsync(jsonItems);
    }
```

But this is runs a bit slow and I am looking for any ideas on how to make this faster.

**Update**
To provide a bit more context based on some of the comments, for a page size of 1000 items here are the steps and the times:

- 1st Step: Get Items from SQL Server using Dapper and load it into a
  POCO (~1-2 seconds)
- 2nd Step: Map Items to a new DTO(<1 second)
- 3rd Step: Loop through items and serialize each into a json string (30-40 seconds)
- 4th Step: Upload to BigQuery (~1 second)

I tried a few other things:

- items.ToList() as suggested by @mjwillis. That came back in sub 1 second.
- I attempted to serialize the entire object without the select, and that process took a similar amount of time (~30 seconds) so I think there may not be much I can do to speed this up

Comment: How slow is it? How fast does it need to be? _As fast as possible as not an answer._

Comment: When you profiled it, how long did the serialisation take? How long did the Upload take?

Comment: currently the serialization for 1000 items takes about 30-40 seconds when running locally,  I have about 200k items in total that I'm paging through. And the upload is around 2-3 seconds.  My ideal is to figure out  a more graceful way to handle the serialization

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Where are `items` coming from? If you do `var bob = items.ToList();` how long does that take to execute?

Comment: You might ultimately find that it's some horrendous SQL query that is selecting more data than it needs and could be optimized/indexed a lot. I would expect the serialization to be taking a lot of time because it's not really a resource intensive operation and ultimately you have X data that must be represented as Y string; not a huge scope for speeding it up.. maybe stringbuilderibg it yourself... far more likely that the performance issue is executing some massive query and dragging 200000 records over the network

Comment: ps; sqlserver can prepare JSON, and connect to http servers, so you can skip the part where you bring it to your client machine just to serialize and upload it: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/http-requests-using-sqlclr

Comment: Do you really need to call `ToList()` here? Where does `IEnumerable<CatalogItem> items` come from?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The `ToList` may not be _necessary_ but at the very least it allows you to see the cost of the enumeration and JSON serialisation (without the `ToList` that cost will be borne by `UploadJsonAsync`).

Comment: thanks for the comments, It looks like there may not be much I can do to speed this up from the current process. The process of serialization of the object is what appears to be slowing down the process irrespective of whether I am looping through the items or not.

Comment: Getting some down votes and votes to close, go ahead and close this if its is a bad question.  I was able to get to a resolution on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the CPU utilization on my machine was barely going up when I ran the job so I decided to run the serialization in a parallel.  This solution  reduced the time for serializing 1000 records down from 30-40 seconds to 8-9 seconds.

```
public async Task InsertCatalogItemsAsync(IEnumerable<CatalogItem> items)
    {
       //---CHANGED THE SELECT STATEMENT TO RUN IN PARALLEL---
        IEnumerable<string> jsonArray = items.AsParallel().Select(i =>
      {
          var serializedItem = JsonSerializer.Serialize(i);
          return serializedItem;
      }).ToList();
        //upload to BigQuery
        await _table.UploadJsonAsync(jsonArray);

    }
```